# Any examples of irregular shaped button layout in Android?

Tags: android, layout

Hi I'm looking to make a UI in Android, where I'm thinking of putting four circular buttons in a diamond formation close to each other. So  I can't have them contained in a grid of squares or they'd overlap each other onclick.

Can anybody point me to a tutorial or example code that has irregular shaped (non-square) buttons?

Comment: I know this is old but was a solution found? I am having a similar problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367068/overlapping-buttons-with-custom-shape

Answer (score 0):

What about a TableLayout just to hold the buttons.  Use the TableLayout as a container to wrap your buttons in. Then anchor the TableLayout where you want the button group.

```
PSUEDOCODE

<TableLayout
  android:id="@+id/ButtonContainer"
  android:layout_width="3XButtonWidth"
  android:layout_height="3XButtonHeight"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="OrWhereYouNeedIt"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="OrWhereYouNeedIt"
  >
  <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/FirstRow">
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+/TopButton"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:AnyOtherParams="true"/>
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/MiddleRow">
    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+/LeftButton"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:AnyOtherParams="true"/>
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+/RightButton"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:AnyOtherParams="true"/>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/LastRow">
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+/BottomButton"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:AnyOtherParams="true"/>
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: If the table is 3 times the button width, that just makes it a standard grid with far too much space between buttons. I want them to be closer. For example, circles in four cells in this grid http://i72.photobucket.com/albums/i163/keytotheleyline7/Shippougrid.jpg

Comment: Then just make the tablelayout = wrap_content height and width.  i will test it later.